# sql server(find the count of table base on condition)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

i have a table  like  following

```
RequestNo  Facility  status 
1           BDC1      Active
1           BDC2      Active
1           BDC3      Active
2           BDC1      Active
2           BDC2      Active
```

i want like this

```
RequestNo  Facilty       Count 
1          BDC (1,2,3)   1
2          BDC(1,2)      1
```

the count should display based on  Status with facilty.Fcilityv should take  as BDC only

Comment: Can you explain the logic?  The example does not quite convey that information.  How do you get the count of 1?

Comment: It'd be easier if you restructured your data so that BCD was in one column and the 1,2,3 were in another.  We can use substring options to get around this, of course, but it's just easier to query the data if you've got it set up properly for what you want to use it for.

Comment: your question seems to be missing two more sections. I tried this {code follows} but it gave me this issue {error message or wrong output}

Answer (score 0):

Try this, (assuming that your facility is fixed 4 character code)

```
SELECT RequestNo, Fname + '(' + FnoList + ')' Facilty, count(*) cnt
FROM 
(
    SELECT  distinct RequestNo, 
    SUBSTRING(Facility,1,3) Fname,
    stuff((
        select ',' + SUBSTRING(Facility,4,4)
        from Dummy
        where RequestNo = A.RequestNo AND
        SUBSTRING(Facility,1,3) = SUBSTRING(A.Facility,1,3)
        for xml path('')
            ) ,
         1, 1, '') as FnoList
    FROM Dummy A
) x
group by RequestNo, Fname, FnoList;
```

[SQL DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5a7a4/3)

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't put any constraints on the length of the Facility field.  It strips out the chars from the beginning and the numeric numbers from the ending:

```
SELECT RequestNo, FacNameNumbers, COUNT(Status) as StatusCount
FROM
(
SELECT DISTINCT
  t1.RequestNo, 
  t1.Status,
  substring(facility, 1, patindex('%[^a-zA-Z ]%',facility) - 1) + 
  '(' +
    STUFF((
      SELECT DISTINCT ', ' + t2.fac_number  
      FROM (
        select distinct 
          requestno, 
          substring(facility, 2 + len(facility) - patindex('%[^0-9 ]%',reverse(facility)), 9999) as fac_number
        from facility    
    ) t2
    WHERE t2.RequestNo = t1.RequestNo 
    FOR XML PATH (''))
  ,1,2,'') + ')' AS FacNameNumbers
FROM Facility t1
) final
GROUP BY RequestNo, FacNameNumbers
```

And the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a9ccc/2)